# Проблема с модулем QT webview/webengine 5.9.8

Tags: qt, webview

Итак, у меня проблема с подключением, и соответственно, с использованием *webview* или *webengine*.
Всё, что я хочу написать для изучения данного модуля - приложение, которое рисует всего одну страничку, допустим, yandex.ru, и чтобы была возможность переходить по кликами мыши по ссылкам, которые уже имеются на прорисованной страничке.
Мною были просмотрены несколько видео - программа вроде как пишется в несколько строчек кода (около 20). Но к сожалению эти видео уже старые, и в версии qt которая у меня установлена, нет возможности даже вытащить на форму объект webview, чтобы там прорисовывалась страничка. 
Как это исправить?

Да, мне известно, что **MinGW не поддерживает работу** с *webview* и *webengine*, поэтому мною были установлены компиляторы **MSVC 2017** для **QT 5.9.8**, также, был установлен модуль QT WebEngine. Но если перейти *"Справка->О модулях..."*, модуля ***webengine*** нет в списке установленных.

Разработка ведется на Windows.

Буду рад любому совету в данном вопросе.

Comment: А в установщике Qt модуль webengine разве не является опциональным?

Comment: @gil9red, верно, этот модуль может быть установлен по нажатию галочки в соответствующем месте. Я это сделал, модуль установлен, **но** это ровным счетом ничего не дало. В QT не появился данный модуль в списке установленных и я не могу пользоваться возможностями данного модуля.

Comment: А вы уверены, что он должен появиться в разделе справки? Что происходит, когда подключаете модуль в `pro`-файле?

Comment: @mkkik, когда подключаю в pro-файле пишется, что указанный модуль не найден. `Unknown module(s) in QT: webengine` - это когда запускаю отладчик через MinGW, а когда через MSVC2017 - в общем у меня еще и плохо настроен MSVC-отладчик. Но это я сейчас пофиксю. Я пробовал на другом компьютере, где отладчик в порядке - и там также `webengine` и `webview` не работали и виджетов не было в дизайнере.

Comment: У вас установлен один `kit`? Модуль установлен с использованием `qmake` именно того профиля, под который сейчас конфигурируете проект?

Comment: @mkkik, у меня установлен только QT 5.9.8 (и имеются 4 компилятора - 2 MinGW [86/64] и два MSVC [86/64])